# Adding HTML elements from Admin page

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, security

What is the safest method of adding an HTML element - (for example, adding a video element to a playlist) - from the admin page? (I'm using PHP)

should I involve the database? for example, I add video links to the database from the admin page, and then the client page has a php snippet that calls all the video links in the DB and echo them? ..

what if I want to append the video elements directly without using the DB? what should I do and how to keep things secure? ..

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

You can try both method to get link.Both method are safe.

1. If you are used db then you can change playlist easily by make admin panel.
2. If you are directly append link then when you want to change playlist then you need to change in code.

So my view db method are best

Comment: I also can append from the admin page, for example I can make a JS function that takes the source of the video and then append the complete video element to the main page (but maybe in this case I need to include the JS page of the admin in the main page) and this is why I asked if it is safe or not .. 

another thing, you recommend the DB method, so.. there is no problem or risk in adding a PHP echo to show the videos? .. 

for example: //fetch video links from db
//concatenate the links inside the video tag (<video source=echo"$link1"/>)
etc....

Comment: In db method I don't thinks any risk.